# Working With Hadoop: localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: bash, hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, java-home

I'm working with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I'm going through the hadoop quickstart manual to make a pseudo-distributed operation. It seems simple and straightforward (easy!).

However, when I try to run `start-all.sh` I get:

```
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

I've read all the other advice on stackoverflow for this issue and have done the following to ensure `JAVA_HOME` is set:

In `/etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh` I have set

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
export JAVA_HOME
```

In `/etc/bash.bashrc` I have set

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

`which java` returns:

```
/usr/bin/java
```

`java –version` works

`echo $JAVA_HOME` returns:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
```

I've even tried becoming root and explicitly writing the in the terminal:

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
$ export JAVA_HOME
$ start-all.sh
```

If you could show me how to resolve this error it would be greatly appreciated.
I'm thinking that my `JAVA_HOME` is being overridden somehow. If that is the case, could you explain to me how to make my exports global?

Comment: When you change your bashrc you need to reset the terminal

Answer (score 71):

I am using hadoop 1.1, and faced the same problem.

I got it solved through changing `JAVA_HOME` variable in `/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` as:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/<jdk folder>
```

Comment: Yes, this was the case. It also works for hadoop-2.6.0. Thanks!

Comment: Works for hadoop-2.7.3

Comment: Works for hadoop-3.0

Comment: Works still for hadoop in year 3038

Comment: Works in 2021, but my localhost still doesn't run.

Comment: Worked for 3.3.4

Answer (score 21):

The way to solve this problem is to export the JAVA_HOME variable inside the conf/hadoop-env.sh file.

**It doesn't matter if you already exported that variable in ~/.bashrc, it'll still show the error.**

So *edit* **conf/hadoop-env.sh** and uncomment the line "export JAVA_HOME" and add a proper filesystem path to it, i.e. the path to your Java JDK.

> # The Java implementation to use. Required.
>    export JAVA_HOME="/path/to/java/JDK/"

Comment: I also had to set it explicitly, not as ${JAVA_HOME}

Comment: @NikitaG. So do I. Even when i echo ${JAVA_HOME} always print the correct value, only set it explicitly works.

Comment: in hadoop-2.7.3, the `hadoop-env.sh` file is located in `hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop` directory instead of the `conf` directory

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same issue on ubuntu LTS 16.04. Running `bash -vx ./bin/hadoop` showed it tested whether java was a directory. So I changed JAVA_HOME to a folder and it worked.

```
++ [[ ! -d /usr/bin/java ]]
++ hadoop_error 'ERROR: JAVA_HOME /usr/bin/java does not exist.'
++ echo 'ERROR: JAVA_HOME /usr/bin/java does not exist.'
ERROR: JAVA_HOME /usr/bin/java does not exist.
```

So I changed JAVA_HOME in `./etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` to

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/
```

and hadoop starts fine.

Answer (score 1):

The way to debug this is to put an "echo $JAVA_HOME" in start-all.sh. Are you running your hadoop environment under a different username, or as yourself? If the former, it's very likely that the JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set for that user.

The other potential problem is that you have specified JAVA_HOME incorrectly, and the value that you have provided doesn't point to a JDK/JRE. Note that "which java" and "java -version" will both work, even if JAVA_HOME is set incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks. I was running it as Root at the time (to avoid permission issues) and it was overriding my JAVA_HOME. I ended up making a new user and giving it the right permissions. The Bash.Bashrc worked with the new username. Everything is great now [ as in new to solve :) ]

Answer (score 1):

extract from etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.  All others are
 optional.  When running a distributed configuration it is best to
 set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
remote nodes.

This means its better and advised to set JAVA_HOME here.. even though the existing definition reads the JAVA_HOME variable. Perhaps its not getting the value of JAVA_HOME from previously set value... standard apache manual does not tell this :( :(

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming from Line 180

```
if [[ -z $JAVA_HOME ]]; then
   echo "Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found." 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
```

in `libexec/hadoop-config.sh`.

Try echo `$JAVA_HOME` in that script. If it doesn't recognize,

Find your `JAVA_HOME` using this:

`$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::")`

and replace the line

`export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}` 
in `/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` with JAVA_HOME you got from above command.

Answer (score 1):

I also had faced the similar problem in **hadoop 1.1**
I had not noticed that the `JAVA_HOME` was commented in: `hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh`

It was

```
/#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
```

Had to change it to

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
```

Comment: I was facing the same,

Answer (score 1):

regardless of debian or any linux flavor, just know that `~/.bash_profile` belongs to specific user and is not system wide. 
in pseudo-distributed environment hadoop works on `localhost` so the `$JAVA_HOME` in .bash_profile is no use anymore.

just export the JAVA_HOME in `~/.bashrc` and use it system wide.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your alternatives is pointing to the right one, you might actually be pointing to a different version and trying to alter the hadoop-env.sh on another installed version.

-alternatives --install /etc/hadoop/conf [generic_name] [your correct path] priority {for further check man page of alternatives}

to set alternatives manually,

alternatives --set [generic name] [your current path].

Answer (score 0):

Change the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `conf/hadoop-env.sh`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/etc/local/java/<jdk folder>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java" >> $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

**Notice: Do not use `export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}` !**

Answer (score -1):

I put it on the first line of file `~/.bashrc`, then it works well!

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`

Comment: This did not work for me.