# Getting error JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, azure-hdinsight

I've installed [HDInsight Emulator](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=HDINSIGHT) and then try to run the hadoop command to create the directory.

Command:hadoop fs -mkdir input/files
I got error JAVA_HOME is not set.
I've already tried below solutions
[Hadoop: «ERROR : JAVA_HOME is not set»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827102/hadoop-error-java-home-is-not-set) 
[Working With Hadoop: localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325594/working-with-hadoop-localhost-error-java-home-is-not-set)

Answer (score 0):

You may not have installed the java sdk, alternatively you may need to specify the location of that SDK in your local environment variables see for example (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows)

After doing that you may need to restart the HDInsight Apache services (depending on how your machine is configured), but will definitely need to restart your command prompt to get the new environment.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Java SDK installation uses the C:\Program Files\ folder, which has a space in the folder name.  This is not compliant with Hadoop.  Consider using the C:\java folder.

Comment: A better method might be to use the shortened version of the Program Files path, or to escape the space when you set it, that way you don't have to put things in non-standard locations on your machine.